# Why I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'serviceId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I can display value of serviceId to console but when I try to compare it in if(), I got this error. Can you tell me why does this happend and how to solve it, please?

- I also tried to put value of servicesCompare1[i].serviceId to variable and I got same error.

  ```
      var servicesCompare1 = [];
      var servicesCompare2 = [];
      $.getJSON("http://localhost:55972/api/status", function (data) {
          self.services(data.services);
          self.lastCheck = data.lastCheck;
          servicesCompare1 = (data.services);
      });

      function DashboardRefresh() {
          self.servicesRefresh = ko.observable([]);
          $.getJSON("http://localhost:55972/api/status", function (data) {
              servicesCompare2 = (data.services);
              self.servicesRefresh(data.services);                
          });
        if (servicesCompare2.length > servicesCompare1.length) {
            for (i = 0; i < (servicesCompare2.length-1); i++) {                   
                console.log(servicesCompare2[i].serviceId);
                if (servicesCompare1[i].serviceId !== servicesCompare2[i].serviceId) {
                    self.services.push(servicesCompare2[i]);

                }
            }
        } 
      }
      setInterval(DashboardRefresh, 5000);
  ```

Console output: 
47
48
49
... other Ids

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'serviceId' of undefined
    at DashboardRefresh (NetworkStatus.html:66)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: So `servicesCompare1[i]` or `servicesCompare2[i]` is undefined.... and you need declare your variable `i`

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition ensures that servicesCompare2 has more items than servicesCompare1. You're then looping through each item in servicesCompare2. This means that at some point, you're going to run into a situation where servicesCompare2 still has items left to traverse, while servicesCompare1 does not.